# How to close a fragment manually in android NavigationComponent

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation

I'm switched to NavigationComponent and i don't know how close fragments manually using this component, in activities we have finish() method that close an activity, i need to do similar thing like this in NavigationComponent.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? You want to close the app? Go back to the previous screen?

Comment: @NightMare Yes, i want to go to the previous screen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use below line in Fragment class:

```
getActivity().getParentFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

**or**
if you are in an activity then you can use

```
getParentFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

Comment: As `getFragmentManager()` is deprecated, just change it to `getParentFragmentManager().popBackStack();`

Comment: While @Roon13 's solution can work, should be careful with this if you're using a bottom menu + navigation controller or multiple fragments. This worked better for me: 
`NavHostFragment.findNavController(this).popBackStack()`

Answer (score 13):

**Kotlin**

I do it in this way

```
findNavController().popBackStack()
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using the Navigation component, you can also simply call `Navigator.popBackStack()` where `Navigator` is your Navigator object.

[Here's](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavController#popBackStack()) the documentation for the NavController

Comment: how to can get the Navigator?
i tried this:
 Navigation.findNavController(getView()).popBackStack();
but nothing happened.

Comment: You can use `Navigation.findNavController(View view)`. Where view is any view in the fragment you want to navigation away from.

Comment: i tried this: Navigation.findNavController(getView()).popBackStack(); but nothing happened.

Comment: Is manually calling `getFragmentManager().popBackStack()` working?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this:

requireActivity().onBackPressed()